# Unlike from the resistive screen, the capacitive one has greater clarity

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

From a test:

> **Unlike** the resistive screen, the capacitive one has greater clarity.

**Unlike** is correct, why **different from** is bad answer ?

Comment: You need to add a few sentences before this one to know if it correct or not (what is conjoined with "the resistive screen).

Comment: We need to see more of the context to understand your question. [Details, please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/6700).

Comment: @BenKovitz the context is not exist this is a question from test and i try to 
understand them.  ______ the resistive screen, the capacitive one has greater clarity. And answer a) Instead of b) Different from c) Unlike

Comment: This is a horrible test question.  It is a qualitative comparison--one has greater clarity, so it is a matter of difference of degree rather than a binary condition that would apply to "unlike".  "Unlike" fits grammatically, but is wrong in terms of meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it happens that *unlike* can be used as a conjunction in this way (as well as an adjective), but *different* cannot.

I'm sorry, but that is the whole of the answer. There aren't magic rules for what grammar particular words have: they just have to be learnt.